# Netlogo : read csv file with a different name at every tick

Tags: csv, file, netlogo

I'd like to read a different file at each ticks of the model, the file name depends on the "current tick"

The initial code is :

```
to load-yield
  reset-timer
  ifelse ( file-exists? "AT_Yield.csv" )
  [
    set yield-data [[][][][][][]]
    set yield-data csv:from-file "AT_Yield.csv"
    user-message "File loading complete!"
    print length yield-data
    file-close
  ]
  [ user-message "There is no AT_Yield.csv file in current directory!" ]

  file-close-all

  print timer
end
```

and I'd like something like here-below where `year` is a global variable initially set up in the interface and then updated at every tick with `set year year + 1`

```
    set yield-data csv:from-file "AT_Yield_" AND year AND ".csv"
```

I cannot find information about how to create somekind of a "dynamic" file name.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I think you are looking for the `word` primitive for creating your file-name

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to LeirsW, here is the solution

```
to load-yield
set yield-file (word "AT_Yield_" year ".csv")
  ifelse ( file-exists? yield-file )
  [
    set yield-data [[][][][][][]]
    set yield-data csv:from-file yield-file
    user-message "File loading complete!"
    print length yield-data
    file-close
  ]
  [ user-message "There is no AT_Yield.csv file in current directory!" ]

  file-close-all
end
```